# Eclipse Footer?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, comments, jautodoc

I have an existing project with many files and was recently informed I need to add a footer on each source file. Does anyone have suggestions of to do this? I'm currently using JAutoDoc to add a header. This has worked well but I can't figure out how to make JAutoDoc add a comment to the bottom. Thanks!

Comment: which OS are you using?Is the footer is same for all java files?i.e Is it fixed one?

Comment: I'm on windows 7. Yes the footer needs to be the same for all the java files. It's actually a copyright notice.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage this using batch file.

1. List all *.java files in source folder(recursively).
2. Iterate all these files and append copy right line at the end of each file.

**Batch script:**

`For /R <Source_Folder_Path> %%G IN (*.java) do Echo "Copyright line to be appended" >> "%%G"`